# Install KDE from scratch on Suse Linux Enterprise Desktop

Tags: linux, kde, suse, sled

I have a SUSE SLED system running without window manager (KDE or GNOME). I don't have the DVD
but I have access to a network repository.

How do I install KDE from scratch?

Thanks.

Comment: what version of SUSE? and Open/Enterprise?

Comment: the version is SLES 10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Yast software manager, switch to the patterns panel and simply install the patterns *KDE4 Desktop Environment* and *KDE4 Base System*.

If you want to upgrade to the latest stable version, add the repositories at http://en.opensuse.org/KDE_repositories#Upstream_release_.28KDE_SC_4.5.29. In Yast software manager pick the repository filter to the just added names, then switch system packages to the versions in each repository. This function is not yet available in the ncurses version of Yast, so get a graphical environment running first with the first-party base repository.

Answer (score 1):

i believe its something like, 'zypper in "KDE package name"'. but its been a while since i used suse.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`zypper update`
`zypper install -t pattern kde4 kde4_basis`

Comment: Thanks!  Me on a fresh install forgot to run `zypper update`!  YaST is such a pain to work with...